# Selenium Webdriver-javaillegalstateexception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying this sample code and I am getting java `illegalstateexception`. How do I resolve this? I have tried the given solution like `setProperty` technique, placing chromedriver exe in C drive.I am getting the error still.

```
package seleniumexample;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Selenium {
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {        
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
      WebDriver Driver=new ChromeDriver();
      Driver.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: What instructions did you use to install the get Chromedriver working?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Rename the driver as "chromedriver.exe"
2. Use "webdriver.chrome.driver"
3. Use the same (both) in setproperty line as well.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Suganthi Govindaraj Did my answer solve your query?